# how can i get byte-array from HBITMAP

Tags: c++, visual-studio, api, winapi, directx

my environment: 
win32
visual c++
directx

i need to map another application's face to my application's texture.
for example, my Internet Explorer screen is appears on my DirectX Cube's Texture, and it is updated realtime.
my Method is Next:

```
//in DirectX Rendering Loop...

HWND hSrc = FindWindow(NULL, _T("application's classname"));
HDC hdc = GetDC(hSrc);

RECT targetRect;
GetClientRect(hSrc, &targetRect);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc,targetRect.right,targetRect.bottom);
//now, target application's window is 'hBitmap'

LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 ptxt = NULL;    //my destination texture
if( SUCCEEDED(D3DXCreateTexture(gpDevice,targetRect.right, targetRect.bottom, 
        0, 0, D3DFMT_A8B8G8R8, D3DPOOL_MANAGED,&ptxt)))
        {
            D3DLOCKED_RECT lr;
            HRESULT hr = ptxt->LockRect(0,&lr,NULL,D3DLOCK_DISCARD);

             //TODO : memcpy(lr.pBits , 'Start pointer of Bit-Array' , targetRect.right*targetRect.bottom*4); //mydesktop's color is 32bit truecolor (= *4)

            ptxt->UnlockRect(0);
        }
```

Question:
how can i get byte array from HBITMAP  format???
there is any method in win32api like this?

GetByteArray(HBITMAP, void**)


or can do this with other method's composition?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144904%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

CreateCompatibleBitmap creates a DDB where you don't have access to the bits. Try using [CreateDIBSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183494.aspx) instead.

Also note that as written you haven't actually painted anything into the bitmap yet.

Comment: the hBitmap is an external application's client main DC. so it is already has a bitmap info and dosent need any drawing. and i need the byte array because the only way that copying HBITMAP's info to IDirect3DTexture9 is using memcpy (lock and unlock that texture)

Comment: @user1101221 No, you only created a bitmap that's compatible with that DC. The DC doesn't itself have a bitmap; that's for in-memory DCs only.